# Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform

I'm starting with Parse and Node.js. I'm trying to retrieve data from Parse db and I don't manage to.

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;

Parse.initialize("*************", "*****************");

module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res, next){
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Event);
        query.find({
          success: function(results) {
            console.log(results);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            console.log(error.message);
          }
        });
    }
}
```

And I got this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
   at Object.Parse.Query (/Users/tchiss_a/test/webapp/node_modules/parse/build/parse-latest.js:7771:33)
   at module.exports.index (/Users/tchiss_a/test/webapp/api/Events.js:7:20)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/tchiss_a/test/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
   at next (/Users/tchiss_a/test/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:100:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/Users/tchiss_a/test/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/tchiss_a/test/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
   at /Users/tchiss_a/test/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:235:24
   at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/tchiss_a/test/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:313:12)
   at /Users/tchiss_a/test/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:229:12
   at Function.match_layer (/Users/tchiss_a/test/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:296:3)
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: `Parse.Event` is probably not what `Parse.Query` expects as constructor argument. Can you please provide a link to the "parse" module?

Comment: A parse module ? I'm using the official Parse npm. http://blog.parse.com/2012/10/11/the-javascript-sdk-in-node-js/

Comment: I can't find a `Event` object in the [parse sources](https://parse.com/downloads/javascript/parse-1.3.2.js), but `Parse.Events`: "`Parse.Events is a fork of Backbone's Events module, provided for your   * convenience.`". This explains the error since the undefined "Event" has no `prototype`.

Comment: Parse.Event is a class that a created in the Parse.com platform. You can see the screenshot below https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BznYkpt5jjfpOFpEbkdERkZIR00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I fixed it. var Event = Parse.Object.extend('Event');

  var query = new Parse.Query(Event);

Comment: @KalelWilfrid you should put this snippet as your answer and close the question

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix listed in the comments, but the actual problem here is that you're treating a user-defined class "Event" like a Parse class.

change

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Event);
```

to

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Event");
```